# How to check consumer data using Kafka Java api

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

This is my consumer code:

```
public class KafkaConsumer  {

    private ConsumerConnector consumerConnector = null;
    private final String topic = "JsonTopic";

    public void initialize() {
          Properties props = new Properties();
          props.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
          props.put("group.id", "testgroup");
          props.put("kafka.topic", "JsonTopic");
          props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "400");
          props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "300");
          props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");

          ConsumerConfig conConfig = new ConsumerConfig(props);
          consumerConnector = Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(conConfig);
    }

    public void consume() throws IOException {
          Map<String, Integer> topicCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();       
          topicCount.put(topic, new Integer(1));

          //ConsumerConnector creates the message stream for each topic
          Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerStreams =consumerConnector.createMessageStreams(topicCount);         

          List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> kStreamList = consumerStreams.get(topic);

          for (final KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> kStreams : kStreamList) {


               ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> consumerItem = kStreams.iterator();

                 while (consumerItem.hasNext())
                 {
                     System.out.println("Message consumed from topic[" + topic + "] : " + new String(consumerItem.next().message()));  
                    // writeToFile(new String(consumerItem.next().message()),"/root/abc.txt");
                 }

          }
          //Shutdown the consumer connector
          if (consumerConnector != null)   
              consumerConnector.shutdown();          
    }
```

Start server:

```
 ./kafka-server-start.sh /usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/etc/kafka/conf.default/server.properties
```

Start prodcuer:

```
    [root@sandbox bin]# ./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic JsonTopic
HI
Hello
```

I don't get any output in console.

```
[root@sandbox ~]# java -jar kafkaconsumer.jar
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, when a consumer is started, **it ignores all existing data in the Kafka topic and will only consume new message coming in after the consumer is started**. Based on your description of order of events, you started your console producer, write messages and then start the Kafka consumer. Thus no message is going to be picked up.  You can try to send some messages after the consumer is started. Alternatively, you can configure the consumer by setting auto.offset.reset to "earliest" for the new consumer in 0.9 and "smallest" for the old consumer. This will pick ensure the consumer to pick up messages already in the Kafka topic before it starts.

Comment: This is not the solution